# How to check if an intent can be handled from some activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, file-type, intentfilter

I have this method so far , but it came up like something is missing

for example I have a file /sdcard/sound.3ga that returns false ( like there is no activity that can handle this type of file ) , But when I open it from the file manager it opens with the media player with no problem

I think this intent is not complete and I need to to something more to make my self sure that the handlerExists variable will be false ONLY if there is no activity that can handle this intent

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(uriString)).toString());
String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(uriString)),mimetype);
boolean handlerExists = intent.resolveActivity(pm) != null;
```

Answer (score 165):

edwardxu's solution works perfectly for me.

Just to clarify a bit:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "No Intent available to handle action");
}
```

Comment: well, with android api 30+, it doesn't always work now)

Comment: if targeting api 30+ check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62856745/4565796

Comment: this gives me "null" when I try to show map. even though there is map installed, and if I continue to call stratActivity, it works fine. so, in short, this doesn't work correct for geo intents

Answer (score 87):

```
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
if (infos.size() > 0) {
    //Then there is an Application(s) can handle your intent
} else {
    //No Application can handle your intent
}
```

Have you tried this intent?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(yourFileHere));
```

Comment: It is because you forgot: intent.setType("text/plain");

Comment: What is the 0 flag here?

Comment: @RyPope it means <no flags>

Comment: If we are using `setPackage()` on the intent, then  this will fail. So, we should go for `Intent.resolveActivity()`

Comment: resolveActivity() often returns an intent even if there's nothing that can actually handle it, so it doesn't work for this.  This does work for me.

Comment: On Android 30+ I tried `Intent.createChooser(intent, "")` and it suggested two apps, but `packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)` returns 0

Answer (score 58):

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null) {
    // No Activity found that can handle this intent. 
}
else{
    // There is an activity which can handle this intent. 
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't always work: resolveActivity can return an intent that can't be handled.  The queryIntentActivities approach works better for me.

Comment: well, with android api 30+, it doesn't always work now)

Comment: @user924 what is the solution to open a URL on any browser available on device? Because "if(intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null)" is always giving null even if chrome available on device.

Answer (score 5):

**The Clear Answer to solve this problem**

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
public static boolean isAvailable(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
   final PackageManager mgr = ctx.getPackageManager();
   List<ResolveInfo> list =
      mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent, 
         PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
   return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work when using `setPackage()` on the intent.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are another Kotlin solution. It works perfectly even for **Android 30+**.
First include this in you app manifest:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="choose-scheme-goes-here" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Then you can check if an intent can be handled with this function:

```
private fun isIntentAvailable(intent: Intent): Boolean {
    val manager = requireContext().packageManager
    val info = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
    return info.size > 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Kotlin If you need to do something when intent is not available,

```
fun isIntentAvailable(context: Context, action: String?): Boolean {
    val packageManager = context.packageManager
    val intent = Intent(action)
    val resolveInfo: List<*> = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
    return resolveInfo.isNotEmpty()
}
```

Implement this method as

```
private const val SAMPLE_INTENT = "com.realwear.barcodereader.intent.action.SCAN_BARCODE"

if(isIntentAvailable(this,SAMPLE_INTENT)){
    //Do Stuff
}
```

If you don't have anything to do,

```
Intent(SAMPLE_INTENT).also { barcodeReaderIntent ->
    barcodeReaderIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
        barcodeReaderIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CODE_128, false)
        startActivityForResult(barcodeReaderIntent, BARCODE_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “If you don’t have anything to do” and the code below it. The code below it sounds like it’s for if the intent is available, but maybe i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Small update for one looking for something similar in 2021 :) Since Android 11 it is not desired to call the package manager, so extra efforts are needed.
So why don't you just wrap startActivity() in try-catch? Or even better - use Rx beautiful error handing:

```
....
.flatMapCompletable { 
      doSomethingThrowable()
          .onErrorResumeNext { completableCallbackIfNotResolvable() }
}
.subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using kotlin extension

```
 fun Context.isIntentAvailable(intent: Intent): Boolean {
    val resolveInfo: List<*> = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
    return resolveInfo.isNotEmpty()
 }
```

**Usage inside fragment**

```
val available = requireContext().isIntentAvailable(this)
```

**Usage inside activity**

```
val available = this.isIntentAvailable(this)
```

Comment: you should use `PackageManager` for your extension fun instead of `Context` and avoid `PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY`

Comment: `this.isIntentAvailable(this)` is unnecessarily verbose. Just use `isIntentAvailable()`