# Android sharing Files, by sending them via email or other apps

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharing

I have a list of files in my android app and I want to be able to get the selected items and send them via email or any other sharing app. Here is my code.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, getListView().getCheckedItemIds());
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 65):

this is the code for sharing file in android

```
Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(myFilePath);

if(fileWithinMyDir.exists()) {
    intentShareFile.setType("application/pdf");
    intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+myFilePath));

    intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        "Sharing File...");
    intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sharing File...");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share File"));
}
```

Below is another method to share PDF file if you have put file provider in manifest

```
Uri pdfUri;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        pdfUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(PDFViewerActivity.this, fileprovider, pdfFile);
} else {
        pdfUri = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
}
Intent share = new Intent();
share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("application/pdf");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pdfUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share file"));
```

Comment: myFilePath is the path of  PDF file in above example. u may find many solutions to select file from SD card in Android. above program just takes file path as input and shows apps on device to share file to. e.g. if u select gmail app, it attaches file and set body and subject text

Comment: In addition to that, I needed to set up a `FileProvider`, this may help: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sharing-Content-with-Intents

Comment: I am still unable to share file. It shows me that error in toast in gmail when I try to attach it there. Kindly help. Thank you

Answer (score 27):

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(exportPath));
```

also you can make `zip file` of all file and attach zip file for send multiple file in android

Comment: Thank a man!You solved my problem.I used  Uri.fromFile(exportPath)) instead of using Uri.parse("file://"+myFilePath) and now can share image.

Answer (score 16):

For those who trying in Kotlin here is the way:

Start the intent like below:

```
 fun startFileShareIntent(filePath: String) { // pass the file path where the actual file is located.
        val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
            type = FILE_TYPE  // "*/*" will accepts all types of files, if you want specific then change it on your need.
            flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "Sharing file from the AppName"
            )
            putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "Sharing file from the AppName with some description"
            )
            val fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                context!!, context!!.packageName + ".provider",
                File(filePath)
            )
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileURI)
        }
        startActivity(shareIntent)
    }
```

In Manifest inside the application tag:

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Under res-->xml--> provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="files" path="." />
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: @YogeshNikamPatil Glad that it helped you. :)

Comment: Won't your third call to `flags` overwrite the first two calls?

Answer (score 14):

This is work for every single file!

```
private void shareFile(File file) {

    Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    intentShareFile.setType(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName()));
    intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
        Uri.parse("file://"+file.getAbsolutePath()));

    //if you need
    //intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Sharing File Subject);
    //intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sharing File Description");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share File"));

}
```

Thanks Tushar-Mate!

Comment: A bit of information what your code does could be helpful for the questioner.

Comment: Amazing - full charm

Comment: What about `FileProvider`?

Answer (score 4):

First you should define File Provider, see https://medium.com/@ali.dev/open-a-file-in-another-app-with-android-fileprovider-for-android-7-42c9abb198c1.

The code checks that a device contains applications which can receive the file, see [How to check if an intent can be handled from some activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407502/how-to-check-if-an-intent-can-be-handled-from-some-activity).

```
fun sharePdf(file: File, context: Context) {
    val uri = getUriFromFile(file, context)

    if (uri != null) {
        val intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            type = "application/pdf" // For PDF files.
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, file.name)
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, file.name)
            // Grant temporary read permission to the content URI.
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        }
        // Validate that the device can open your File.
        val activityInfo = intent.resolveActivityInfo(context.packageManager, intent.flags)
        if (activityInfo?.exported == true) {
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                "Share PDF file")
        }
    }
}

fun getUriFromFile(file: File, context: Context): Uri? =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Uri.fromFile(file)
    } else {
        try {
            FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.packageName + ".provider", file)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw if (e.message?.contains("ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData") == true) {
                Error("FileProvider is not set or doesn't have needed permissions")
            } else {
                e
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE) for delivering multiple data to someone

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, arrayUri);
intent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(intent);
```

The `arrayUri` is the Array List of  Uri of files to Send.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example to share or save a text file:

```
private void shareFile(String filePath) {

    File f = new File(filePath);

    Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    File fileWithinMyDir = new File(filePath);

    if (fileWithinMyDir.exists()) {
        intentShareFile.setType("text/*");
        intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + filePath));
        intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "MyApp File Share: " + f.getName());
        intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "MyApp File Share: " + f.getName());

        this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, f.getName()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + File.separator + DIRECTORY_VIDEO);
            String fileName = mediaModel.getContentPath().substring(mediaModel.getContentPath().lastIndexOf('/') + 1, mediaModel.getContentPath().length());
            File fileWithinMyDir = new File(directory, fileName);
            if (fileWithinMyDir.exists()) {
                Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", fileWithinMyDir);
                Intent intent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                        .setStream(fileUri) // uri from FileProvider
                        .setType("text/html")
                        .getIntent()
                        .setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND) //Change if needed
                        .setDataAndType(fileUri, "video/*")
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808296/android-send-intent-for-file-puts-data-uri-into-gmail-recipient-field . Could you maybe share your Manifest part for the FileProvider and your provider path xml file?

Comment: <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

Comment: This is Manifest part you can try this in your manifest file.

Comment: XML Part is :    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>

Comment: @Oliver thanks for asking may be your problem is solved from above solution if not then please tell me.

Comment: Hey Alok, thanks for the information. As I edited in my question, the problem was something else. Still thanks! I like your ShareCompat solution here too. Upvote from me ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
val uriArrayList: ArrayList<Uri> = ArrayList()
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    runCatching {
        itemsList!!.forEach {
            uriArrayList.add(
                FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    mContext,
                    APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    File(it.path)
                )
            )
        }

    }.onSuccess {
        requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
            if (uriArrayList.size > 0) {
                val intent = Intent()
                intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriArrayList)
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                intent.type = "image/*|application/pdf/*"
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, resources.getString(R.string.share)))
            }
        }
    }
        .onFailure {
            Log.e("SHARING_FAILED", it)
        }
}
```

First of all you have to write provider code in app manifest file for sharing on android 7.0 and above

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

here provider_paths are:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="/storage/emulated/0" path="."/>
    <root-path name="root" path="." />
    <files-path name="files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was facing issue but after adding /storage/emulated/0 that error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did like this, because I needed a response from sharing

Manifest.xml

```
 <provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Under res-->xml--> provider_paths.xml

```
    <paths>
      <external-path name="external" path="." />
      <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
      <files-path name="files" path="." />
    </paths>
```

ExtendedFun.kt

```
fun Context.shareFileIntent(filePath: String, fileType: String): Intent {
    val fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "$packageName.provider", File(filePath))
    return Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
        type = fileType
        flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "Sharing file from the AppName"
        )
        putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            "Sharing file from the AppName with some description"
        )
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileURI)
    }
}
```

In MainActivity

```
private val shareFile =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            startActivity(result.data)
        }else{
            Log.d("shareFile", "the sharing was cancelled")
        }
    }
```

Finally call like this

```
shareFile.launch(
   shareFileIntent(filePath, "text/plain")
)
```

Answer (score -5):

Read this article about [Sending Content to Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();

sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");

sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```