# Share text file via Intent from internal storage

Tags: android, android-intent, internal-storage, android-internal-storage

I create a bunch of text files which I created like in the code below. I saved those files in internal storage. My goal now is to display it in ListView and if user gonna click on an item it should open or send the file via intent (e.g. email).

```
static void createFile (Context context) {
    mTimeStamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
    try {
        String fileName = "File_" + mTimeStamp + ".txt";
        mContext = context;
        mOutputStreamWriter = new 
        OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(fileName ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        String path = mContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Creating file: " +  path, 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error with creating file writer...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static void writeToFileData(String dataToSave) {
    try {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Saving data to file: " +  dataToSave, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mOutputStreamWriter.write(dataToSave);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error with writing to file...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static void closeFileWriter() {
    try {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Closing file... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mOutputStreamWriter.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error with closing file writer...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then I list my all files like this (not in ListView but only for test now):

```
static void testDispFiles (Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    String path = mContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    Log.v(TAG, "testDisp path: " + path);
    File dirFile = new File(path);

    File[] files = dirFile.listFiles();
    Log.v(TAG, "testDisp length: " + files.length);

    for (File f: files) {
        Log.v(TAG, "testDisp file: " + f.getName());
    }
}
```

And now I want to share one of the files by sending it through e.g. email. How to send the text file from internal storage via intent?

//Edit:

I create an Intent which returning the toast "You can't add this file" message from Gmail app.

```
String path = mContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
File f = new File(path);
File[] files = f.listFiles();
Uri data = Uri.fromFile(files[0]);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,data);
i.setType("plain/text");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: You can use TinyDB to store String in the internal storage and then can get it: TinyDB.class [here](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo/blob/master/TinyDB.java)

Comment: Use `FileProvider`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you help me with this? I never use the FileProvider.

Comment: I pointed you to documentation, and [here is some more](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html). [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/Camera/FileProvider) from [one of my books](https://commonsware.com/Android) that shows using `FileProvider` for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and `ACTION_VIEW`. If you have additional concerns about how to use `FileProvider`, and you cannot find existing materials on the topic, ask a separate Stack Overflow question with your specific problems.

Comment: For Kotlin, you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62928442/2462531

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found one of solution for this problem. How @CommonsWare suggested I used a FileProvider. I follow this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYvV4m-N9oY). But in **provider_paths.xml** I put this code, because I use a internal storage.

```
<Paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="files" path="."/>
</Paths>
```

Then in activity I send a file via intent like this:

```
       Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"same_authoritory_which_was_in_manifest", new File(FILE_TO_SAVE.getPath()));
       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Test");
       i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
       i.setType("plain/*");
       startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You store your files using `openFileOutput()` which is indeed in internal private memory of your app. Like `getFilesDir()`.

No other apps have access.

If you want to share the files then you have to serve them using a file provider.

For the rest sharing a file is a standard action.

You can find code all over the place.

Comment: Could you help me with this one? Because I never use file providers and I don't know how to work with it.

Comment: Google for it. You can find code all over the place.

Comment: You could just start with code for the share intent. Please post. Google for Intent.ACTION.SEND and Intent.EXTRA_STREAM.

Comment: I tried to send it with this code: [my code](https://pastebin.com/3ZLywpaC).

But when I choose a gmail app, I get a "You can't add this file".