# android studio share CSV file request contain no data

Tags: android

I want to share my csv file to any action like Bluetooth, send to email ,etc

```
 final String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Folder" + "/" + "mycsv.csv";



  Intent sharingIntent = new Intent();
                        sharingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, filename);
                        sharingIntent.setType("text/comma_separated_values/csv");
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share file with"));
```

the output will be no request containt no data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `filename` requires a `file://` prefix. Android, for sharing any types of file requires a universal identifier or a `Uri`.

```
final String fileUriString = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Folder" + "/" + "mycsv.csv";
```

Also, change the `type` to `text/csv`.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent();
sharingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse( fileUriString ) ) ;
sharingIntent.setType("text/csv");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share file with"));
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985646/android-sharing-files-by-sending-them-via-email-or-other-apps) for more.

Comment: It worked on me now i only just have missing file://