# Android: webView app crashes

Tags: android

I have a `webView` app. Is a list of links to some tv online streaming channels.

Some links are m3u8 and others are sop.

If I access a m3u8 link it opens in default media player, if i try to open the sop links, and I do not have SopCast Player installed, my app crashes, 
and I got the error below.

If I have installed SopCast Player, evetrything is ok.

I'm now with Android.

My files:
[Manifest](http://pastebin.com/SpLm70j7)

[ManinActivity](http://pastebin.com/NSzMhRpd)

Error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=sop://111.175.143.195:3912/151638 }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
at com.example.tv.MainActivity$1.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(MainActivity.java:47)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:239)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:346)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please, please, please, help me!!
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your shouldOverrideUrlLoading() you should replace `startActivity(i);` with

```
try {
  startActivity(i);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
  // do what you want if appropriate app is not installed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It crashes *because* the app is not installed. What did you expect would happen?

You need to first check if the package is installed *before* calling the `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty much self-explanatory. the Android system doesn't know how to handle that URL.

You can just wrap your

```
   startActivity(i);
```

in a `try/catch`-block (and inform the user of the problem in `catch`), or you can check beforehand if the system can handle that Intent as [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407502/how-to-check-if-an-intent-can-be-handled-from-some-activity).