# How to identify android devices that do not understand ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS intent

Tags: android

In Android we do have an option to go directly to App Usage Settings screen by firing below intent :

```
Intent intenta = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
```

But there are few devices in Samsung and LG (not all) which has customized OS and does not take directly to "APP USAGE ACCESS" screen even after firing above intent, rather it just takes user to "SETTINGS" screen. My question is how do I identify such devices and separate them so that I can take care of their actions separately

Comment: have a look here, it's a way to find if there will be an activity that can handle the action http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407502/how-to-check-if-an-intent-can-be-handled-from-some-activity

Comment: Thanks @user45678. I tried that but this intent "Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS" in Samsung Tab 4 model only takes you till SETTINGS screen and not to the actual PERMISSION screen. Hence according to code, it passes but in real its not the right expected behavior