# Android doesn't add a timer

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to do an App to set a timer in my phone with an `Intent` but I don't know why it doesn't do anything when I tried to set the timer.

Here's my code:

```
public void setTimerClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_TIMER);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, descriptionAlarm.getText().toString());
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_LENGTH, String.valueOf(timeTimer.getText().toString()));
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
}
```

And there isn't any error message in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you use permission SET_ALARM ?

Comment: and why startActivityForResult?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yes I use the permission!

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I tried startActivity and startActivityForResult, the both.

Comment: what are you expecting? By the way `AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true` doesn´t display an UI, so no AlarmClock starts visuell. If you are awaiting the clock app to start you have to set this to false.

Comment: And, it´s just unlikely but possible, if your device doesn´t implement a system clock app that listens to `AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_TIMER` intent, nothing will happen.....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs What I want is to set a timer in my phone via my App. To set a chronometer.

Comment: you should check if the intent can be handled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407502/how-to-check-if-an-intent-can-be-handled-from-some-activity. If not, then it´s like I said, no clock app is listening to the intent and you can´t deal with that intent..

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I've checked if an intent can be handled from some activity and it seems to be handled from some activity... but anything is happening in my App hahaha.