# ScreenSaver App for Android TV using DayDream Service- There was a problem in parsing the package

Tags: android-studio, android-tv, screensaver, television, daydream

I am trying to make an app for Android Tv it is a screen saver app I am taking help from an official document from Google and this link

[https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2012/12/daydream-interactive-screen-savers.html]

Here is my manifest file the app is simply using DayDream Service to load the URL on WebView, if I install this app on my phone it works perfectly( am talking about the only installation, I still have a problem in running screen saver), but before that how do I resolve this error? 
**"There was an error in parsing the package"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:banner="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name="Screensaver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="WebView">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.dreams.DreamService" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="SetURL"
        android:label="Dream URL"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="SetURLInteractive"
        android:label="Dream URL (Interactive)"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407502/how-to-check-if-an-intent-can-be-handled-from-some-activity. If there is no app that handle the intent then there is nothing you can do

Comment: @Raghunandan i have ttorrent installed on my phone but just for the sake of experiments i tried installing bitTorrent , utorrent also but nothing seems to be working for me , What i really think is that there is no such Intent handling function defined in torrent clients

Comment: you can check if a intent can be handled by existing apps on phone using PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
`if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "No Intent available to handle action");
}`

Comment: I tried this still same error _no app can handle this intent_ but i have installed each and every _ttorrent_ client application, i think there is something wrong with the type of the file i changed it to text/plain still no response am gonna leave this now as nothing is working

Comment: that code is only checks if there is an app that can handle your intent.

Comment: okay, but i want to open the selected file in ttorrent application using intent
i know the code to check if there is an app that handle intent, i just want to know how to open that file in ttorrent using intents which i am unable to do :(