# How to detect Setaction in intent android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I tried to open pdf using pdf reader.
but im getting no application found.

how can i find is there any application available before showing the message.

I want to open the application popup only if any application exist to open the pdf file how can i add it?

```
Intent target = new Intent();
target.setType("application/pdf");
target.setData(Uri.parse(attachment));
target.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
```

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407502/how-to-check-if-an-intent-can-be-handled-from-some-activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
 Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file); 
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(attachment), "application/pdf"); 
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 

 try { 
      startActivity(intent); 
   }  
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { 
       Toast.makeText(OpenPdf.this,  "No Application Available to View PDF",  
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
   }
```

Comment: So after adding the package it will only open in adobe reader?@vishal-vaishnav

Comment: yaa definetely...

Comment: i want that open any app available. If no app available i want to show toast no need for the popup how to add it?@vishal-vaishnav

Comment: I updated answer ..Try this